# How can I make my page load faster - delay is coming from third party plugins (mainly facebook)

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, time, load

I have a blog page that I created www.fullyawaken.com (for reference).

My problem is that it is taking forever to load initially (60-70s), but after it is loaded once, it goes back down to under 2-3 seconds, unless you hit command + shift + r.

I've located the source of the slowdown to be the facebook plugins - I have like page/like + share button/ and comments section. It is massively affecting the load time of my website. My google pagespeed score is at 89 when I comment out all the plugins and at 40 when I have them in.

Can you give me a solution that isn't to simply remove the plugins. Or even if it has to come to that, give me some guidance as to how to proceed from there (alternatives to my facebook plugin that wouldn't slow down the page) I don't want to build a dynamic comment section on my own, but I also don't want to sacrifice that much speed for the utility.

I don't know if that is important, but my code is structured so:

I have php files that call information from a couple of different segmented sources to compile a page - above the fold I am calling my css and below I am calling one of my two control files. In there I have navigation bar capabilities + on.load function animations and an on.load call to my other control file that contains the necessary javascript from facebook and twitter for the working plugins (I thought that this on.load necessary for the javascript plugins would mean that my page + animations and pictures can load before the plugins start loading, thus minimizing page load time, but this hasn't worked)

So, I have async loading - and the scripts seem to be loading in <3-5 seconds, but the whole webpage DOM load is still delayed for a whole minute ? it doesn't make any sense. And yet, if I remove the plugins from the page it is much faster. Google pagespeed says I should enable compression for all of the facebook addons as a main insight regarding to load time - but I do have compression enabled on my server. Someone please explain this to me..

Comment: You can try to make your Facebook and Twitter plugins to be loaded asynchronously. Just like this: `<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5&amp;appId=482304528617887" async></script>`

Comment: Yeldar, supposedly the code I have is loading async, but it isn't making any difference on the load time..

Comment: For some reason, even if it loads the script super fast it still says that it takes it a minute to load, and on google speed insights it says I should enable compression on the facebook plugins. But I have enabled compression for my server so I don't know what more i can do.